# MediaMetadataRetriever extractMetadata string encoding

Tags: java, android

When I use the `extractMetadata( MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE )` function.

Some of the strings returned are displayed incorrectly.

i.e.

> Christina Perri - A Thousand Years

is displayed as

> 䌀栀爀椀猀琀椀渀愀 倀攀爀爀椀 ⴀ 䄀 吀栀漀甀猀愀渀搀 夀攀愀爀猀

Does anyone have any tips as to how I can get the string to display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about Android, but there are two possibilities

1. You are reading it correctly and someone used this characters while storing the data.
2. You get the wrong characters because the text you get, has been stored in a different enconding, than you are using to display it. In this case you need to tell Java in which encoding this string is.

A good start to read about encodings is this [blog](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

The [Java tutorial for working with text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/index.html)

Comment: Yep, you're 100% right it's to do with encoding. I gave up trying to make sense of why MediaMetadataRetriever has issues and switched to the open source MyID3 which works great out of the box.

http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/